# Create a function that follows a moving text on a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a function to move data between table cells but the functions never seem to stick to whatever tag is "attached" to the cell itself. I'm not sure if I was using ids wrong. I need help finding a way to "attach" a function to a tag that moves between cells.
Can you help me create a button to move a tag (unit 1) upwards and downwards through a table such that it stops at the end of the table?

Original code attached here

```js
//Send to the "bottom"
function sendOS() {
  var node = document.getElementById("r1c1").lastChild;
  document.getElementById("r1c3").appendChild(node);
  /*
    var node = document.getElementById("r1c3").lastChild;
  document.getElementById("r1c2").appendChild(node);
  */
}

//Send to the "top"
function sendTop() {
  var node = document.getElementById("r1c2").lastChild;
  document.getElementById("r1c1").appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="r1c1">Unit1</th>
      <td id="r1c2">Unit2</th>
        <td id="r1c3">Unit3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td id="r2c1">r1c2</td>
    <td id="r2c2">r2c2</td>
    <td id="r2c2">r2c3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td id="r2c2">r3c1</td>
    <td id="r2c2">r3c2</td>
    <td id="r2c2">r3c3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--Table ends -->
<!-------------------------------------------------------------->


<button onclick="sendOS()">move to the other side</button>
<button onclick="sendTop()">move to the right</button>
```

Comment: Could you explain what the result would be when you would click one of the two buttons. Would the **Unit 1** cell replace the position of another cell or join in the same cell (as it does now). Should the other cells move along so that no two, or more, cells are on the same position at any time. If you have any means of visualizing your intention, it would help a lot!

Comment: Got it. The buttons are a bit misleading but basically, "move to the other side" sends anything from row 1 column 1 to row 1 column 3. The next button moves anything from row 1 column 2 to row 1 column 1.  What I'm looking for are functions to move tags within the center table either left or right or up or down. Lets say a button to move a <p> tag left and another one to move it right and so on.

Comment: I'm going to try to attach an image or a gif of what I'm looking for when I get some time. Not sure if I can do it in the comments section.

Comment: I can't post an image via comments (if you know how let me know). Basically I'm trying to find a way to find functions (controlled via buttons) to move a table cell's contents left, right, up, or down in such a way that it stops at the end of the table.

Comment: And if those functions could be controlled by keys on the key board, that would be really great! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with creating all that. You should try it out for yourself, you'll learn a lot more.

But I can help you with the code you provided.

- A lot of your `id` attributes are the same.  Every `id` on the page should be unique.
- Change your HTML structure slightly by adding a `<span>` around the texts inside your cells (`<td><span id="target-1">Text</span></td>`). That way you can select elements inside your cells and move those around. Using `lastChild` to get the `TextNode` is not the right approach.
- The functions should check if there is a cell next to it in the direction you want to move the text. If there is, move the text. If not, then do nothing.

Below I've made a small demonstration on how this might work. Here `target` is the element that we move. It's the `<span id="target">Foo</span>` element in the HTML.

When clicking either button, the code will go one element up from the `target` element with `parentElement`, that will be the `<td>` our target is in.
It then tries to access the previous or next `<td>` in the row (depending on the direction). If a neighbouring `<td>` is found, it will append the element.

The advantage of this approach is that you always have a reference to the element that you are moving.

```js
const target = document.querySelector('#target');
const buttonLeft = document.querySelector('.js-target-move-left');
const buttonRight = document.querySelector('.js-target-move-right');

function targetMoveLeft() {
  const previousCell = target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  
  if (previousCell) {
    previousCell.append(target);
  }
}

function targetMoveRight() {
  const nextCell = target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  
  if (nextCell) {
    nextCell.append(target);
  }
}

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', targetMoveLeft);
buttonRight.addEventListener('click', targetMoveRight);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="target">Foo</span></td>
      <td><span>Bar</span></td>
      <td><span>Baz</span></td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="js-target-move-left">Left</button>
<button class="js-target-move-right">Right</button>
```

I hope this will at least push you in the right direction. Good luck with implementing the other features.

Comment: This was what I was looking for thanks! I'll worry about the rest myself but you definitely put me in the right direction. Appreciate it!

Comment: Does Foo Bar Baz mean anything?

Comment: You're welcome. Nah, [Foo Bar, Baz and Quz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) are simply placeholders used in many programming examples. Feel free to accept the answer (the checkmark top left of the quetsion) if it helped you out.